# Download zip file

Tags: blazor-server-side

i have a zip folder in my wwwroot/files

how will i let the user download this file?

though about making a controller with something like this, but this is clearly wrong and it fails. It just does nothing even though it is reading the bytes and returning correctly

```
[HttpGet("DownloadOutput")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Invoice(string JobId)
        {
            string file = Directory.EnumerateFiles($"***PATH***\\{JobId}", "*.*",
                                              SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(n => Path.GetExtension(n) == ".zip").FirstOrDefault();

            //converting file into bytes array  
            var dataBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);

            //adding bytes to memory stream   
            var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new();
            httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = file;
            httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return Ok(httpResponseMessage);
        }
```

calling the file from my blazor code like this.

```
var result = await Http.GetAsync($"Inventer/DownloadOutput?jobId=JobId}");
```

Comment: Do we really speak about Blazor server-side? If zip files are in a sub-dir of wwwroot, they can be downloaded as static files without any specific code. Please give more details if necessary.

Comment: @GuyatMercator i found out that downloading multiple files is not possible because chroome blocks it. So will have to .zip it . used this code so far. but ofcouse triggering the save as would have been somehow better. So chrome would not block downloading files